# Scikit-learn using GridSearchCV on DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I tried to use GridSearchCV on DecisionTreeClassifier, but get the following error:
TypeError: unbound method get_params() must be called with DecisionTreeClassifier instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

here's my code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import  cross_val_score

X, Y = createDataSet(filename)
tree_para = {'criterion':['gini','entropy'],'max_depth':[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,15,20,30,40,50,70,90,120,150]}
clf = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier, tree_para, cv=5)
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 12):

In your call to `GridSearchCV` method, the first argument should be an instantiated object of the `DecisionTreeClassifier` instead of the name of the class. It should be

```
clf = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), tree_para, cv=5)
```

Check out the example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) for more details.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

Another aspect regarding the parameters is that grid search can be run with different combination of parameters. The parameters mentioned below would check for different combinations of `criterion` with `max_depth`

```py
tree_param = {'criterion':['gini','entropy'],'max_depth':[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,15,20,30,40,50,70,90,120,150]}
```

If needed, the grid search can be run over multiple set of parameter candidates:

For example:

```py
tree_param = [{'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'], 'max_depth': max_depth_range},
              {'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf_range}]
```

In this case, grid search would be run over two sets of parameters, first with every combination of `criterion` and `max_depth` and second, only for all provided values of `min_samples_leaf`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for decision tree Grid Search

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def dtree_grid_search(X,y,nfolds):
    #create a dictionary of all values we want to test
    param_grid = { 'criterion':['gini','entropy'],'max_depth': np.arange(3, 15)}
    # decision tree model
    dtree_model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
    #use gridsearch to test all values
    dtree_gscv = GridSearchCV(dtree_model, param_grid, cv=nfolds)
    #fit model to data
    dtree_gscv.fit(X, y)
    return dtree_gscv.best_params_
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a () after the classifier:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), tree_para, cv=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is still there try to replace :

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

with

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

It sounds stupid but I had similar problems and I managed to solve them using this tip.